# Question on discrete probability functions

Tags: statistics

Choose a random integer. What is the probability that the integer will be  even? Obviously $\frac{1}{2}$. But how is this obvious when using the definition of a discrete probability function?

Let $A$ be the event, choose an even integer in the sample space of all integers, $S$. Then $$P(A) = \Sigma_{s \in A} P(s)$$

How does this equal $\frac{1}{2}$? Does $P(s)=0$ for all $s \in S$...?

Thanks

Comment: "choose a random integer" doesn't make sense

Comment: To build on @mathworker21's comment, you can only pick a random integer after specifying a probability distribution on the integers. You can check that there cannot be a uniform probability distribution on the integers. (suppose there were...)

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Suppose there were. Choose two random integers $x,y$. Then by symmetry, $\Pr(x\ge y) = 1/2$; however, for any fixed $x$, $\Pr(y>x) = 1$.

Comment: @mathworker21 I meant it as a question for the OP, but I don't know if that's the clearest argument. Suppose there were, then $P(x) = P(0)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$. Now $P(\{0, \ldots, n\}) = n \cdot P(0)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$. If $P(0) > 0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ such that $N \cdot P(0) > 1$ (by the archimedean property if you like). In other words, $P(\{0, \ldots, N\}) > 1$, which is absurd. Hence $P(0) = 0$. But then $P(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, so $P(\mathbb{Z}) = 0$, which contradicts the definition of a probability measure.